# jQuery image swap - strange behavior in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a small JS function running to change a gif on mouseover. It basically works like this:
in the bottom layer there's a gif looping that is switched on mouseenter to a different one.
There is another gif layered above that one, that shows the transition between those two states, wich is also switchend on mouseenter. This second gif does not loop and ends on a transparent frame, to reveal the gif underneath - sounds a bit complicated, so just have a look at my jsfiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/Njw95/](http://jsfiddle.net/Njw95/4)

now it's working perfectly in safari and firefox, but there's a small problem with chrome:
just before the upgrade animation is supposed to play, there's a millisecond of a random frame blinking. I could identify this frame to be the first frame of the "downgrade" animation. I changed th first frame of the downgrade animation to be black. Now in chrome, there's a black flash on mouseenter and mouseleave... in other browsers only on mouseleave...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".col1").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#levelup").attr('src', 'http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/upgrade.gif');
    $("#mainpic").attr('src', 'http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/level2.gif');
});
$(".col1").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#levelup").attr('src', 'http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/downgrade_tr.gif');
    $("#mainpic").attr('src', 'http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/standard.gif');
});
});
```

Comment: This is unrelated, but `img` is self-closing: `<img/>`, not `<img></img>`.

Comment: Also, since you're using jQuery, you can use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover), which accepts two function parameters for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, to simplify your code.

Comment: I just tried this out on both Firefox and Chrome, I never noticed any difference?

Comment: @AstroCB thanks for the hints - changed it to hover. But it's still flashing.

Comment: Your jsfiddle worked as I'd expect for me on chrome and safari

Comment: @Leth0 - It may be a little hard to spot and it only happens  on mouseenter: there's a tiny flash before the upgrade animation plays... just hover over it several times and you will notice... to better illustrate what i mean, i changed the first frame of the downgrade animation to be completely black

Comment: @ChrisMcCabe i added a black frame on the downgrade animation. Now obiously on mouseleave there's a black frame showing... but that same black frame flashes for a millisecond on mouseenter (only sometimes)... this is only happening in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some gif images cache bug in Chrome.
You can instead **request always a new image**. Fixed the issue for me:

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Njw95/6/)**

JS:

```
var $pic = $("#pic"),
    path = "http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/";

$pic.hover(function( e ) {
   var mE = e.type=="mouseenter";
   var s = new Image(); s.src = path+(mE?"upgrade":"downgrade_tr")+".gif";
   var b = new Image(); b.src = path+(mE?"level2":"standard") +".gif";
   $pic[0].src = s.src;
   $pic[0].style.backgroundImage = "url("+ b.src +")"; 
});
```

HTML (yes, all you need)

```
<img id="pic" src="http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/standard.gif">
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;}
#pic {
    background: url(http://studio-bonsei.de/bilder/empty.gif) no-repeat 50% 50% / cover ;
    width: 50%;
}
```